# Tour shows that SE consist of 127 communities and help center shows 128

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour

> [image]

Vs.

> [image]

Upgrade needed?

**Edit**

Sorry, you mishit the target. Please try again.

Comment: Hmm, 127 should be the correct number.

Comment: @Anna 127 communities, 1 Area 51, 1 Worldbuilding in private beta and probably 2 that reached beta then got closed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard My point is that I'm pretty sure 127 is the correct number that should be currently shown for the purposes of that page (and for that matter, the tooltip over the site switcher).

Comment: @Anna nope, Worldbuilding is not in [the list](http://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest), which contains exactly 127 sites/communities. Agree about 127 being correct, just trying to figure where the 131 came from.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, I miscounted (comment edited to account for that). Don't really care where the 131 came from. Or at least, it's not necessary to figure that out by guessing. :)

Comment: @Anna fair enough, guess fixing the Help Center banner is easy for you. :)

Comment: Search (Ctrl+F) for "Q&A" on this page - http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic and you get 129 hits. 128 sites + Area 51. I wonder if the first number excludes the current site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we'll exclude private betas from the counts and the site count in the site switcher tooltip and the hero text should match.

Comment: Mission failed.

Comment: @nicael it's most likely counting Area 51 which belongs to Stack Exchange, but is not listed in the sites list. Not sure it's a bug.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be 128. Site switcher includes A51, so to be consistent on Q&A sites, we gotta count it everywhere.