# Where do Stack Exchange Network sites count come from?

Tags: discussion, tooltips

If you hover over the Stack Exchange logo (top left) you will get a tooltip message saying "A list of all ***149*** Stack Exchange sites".

Screenshot:

> [image]

Where do the count of SE Network sites come from? Is it dynamically generated or by some other mechanism? Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [answer from Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239794) I expect this to be dynamically determined, probably based on the [number of databases available](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/344613).

```
select count(*) as [#sites]
from sys.databases 
where database_id > 5 -- exclude system db's and DataExplorer
and name not like '%.Meta'
```

You'll notice the number is 147 there. That is because [Open Sience](http://openscience.stackexchange.com/) and [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/) went live Tuesday and SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.

Comment: Thank you. rene your're SQL master... So based on your query, they all come from one single database? the reason for asking was the count differs on [SO Careers 132](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) and [StackExchange.com 154](http://stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Not everything is on the same code base that could explain the differences there. StackExchange should be inline though so that might be a bug. Don't know it that is true for careers

Comment: As for the Meta.SE goes, your answer solves my question. I will dig more for other mis-match.